# 8 - How to configure system link

Tags: 8, uri

I'm new to drupal, I'm trying to change the link structure and still did not get.

For example, when I create a basic page, it uses a standard link "node/drux"

but I want the link to be the title of the page, without having to create an alternative URL.

How can I change this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) I think. It allows you to define patterns for how the aliases should be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal saves its own url, usually node/nid (nid is the id of the node), but you can create an alias in node edit -> URL path settings.

Comment: I saw this setting within the page, but I don't understand why for every page I'll create an alternative? I can not create this pattern ja friendly way links?

Comment: In that case, as Berdir said, you are looking for Pathauto.